# Facebook UI feed size not adjusting

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, sencha-touch-2

Fb.UI feed is not displaying with the correct width, when the dialog renders it doesnt adjust to the screen size, except for iphone 4 and 4s. With my ipod touch, and android its bigger than the screen. im using sencha touch framework. is there a way to adjust the size of the dialog.
I tried using  FB.UIServer.Methods["fbml.dialog"].size = {width:300, height:555}; but it says FB.UIServer its undefined.

Any help would be apreciated

```
function publishStory() {
    FB.ui({
        access_token:accsstkn,
        method: 'feed',
        name: 'APP',
        caption: 'caption',
        display: 'touch',
        description: description,
        link: 'https://',
        picture: img,
    }, 

    function(response) {
        if (response && response.post_id) {
            alert('Successfully Saved');
            var postid = response.post_id;
            return response.post_id;
        } else {
            alert('Try Again');
        }
    }
    );

    return false;
}

publishStory();
```